# Factorising Multivariable Polynomial of an Ellipse

Tags: factoring

I'm trying to factor:

$ 4xy-8y^2-2x^2+9x=0$

The equation is an ellipse so it should be possible to get this into the form $\frac{(x-a)^2}{p} + \frac{(y-b)^2}{q} - c=0$

I've tried "completing the square" in several ways but I can't find any nice way to deal with the $4xy$ term since it has both variables.
Thanks!

Comment: This ellipse is rotated. You need to find the rotation which eliminates the $xy$ term.

Comment: @user58697 I've never come across this idea before. How would you do that?

Comment: Consider $x = u\cos\alpha + v\sin\alpha$ and $y = -u\sin\alpha + v\cos\alpha$. That's a rotation. Now plug it in the original equation, and find $\alpha$ such that $uv$ vanishes. Complete the squares, and substitute back to $x, y$. The result will not be in the form you are after (it does not exist); it will have $x$ and $y$ in both terms.

Answer (score 1):

The ellipse writes in matrix form
$$
(\mathbf{x-c})^T \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{x-c}) 
= \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} - 2\mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}
+ \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{c}
= R^2
$$
From the equation you give, by identification
$$
\mathbf{A}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -2 \\ -2 & 8
\end{pmatrix},
\mathbf{c} =
\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\ 3/4
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and thus $R^2=27/2$.